# SSRS: Dynamic Size of Subreports

Tags: c#, reporting-services

We have a set of Subreports, which can be parametrized and are shown on a list of Reports. The problem is, these reports don't have a pre-defined margin, so sometimes there is more space for the content and sometimes less.

But I couldn't make it work to tell the Subreport to resize dynamically in the width. Even if I put it in a Rectangle or Grid, the Subreport has just the size he has on the Sub-Report itself, and not the one I tell him to have via MainReport-Designer.

Is there any possibility to make a Subreport resize in width dynamically?

Comment: What if the width of the actual report output is more than you have defined in main report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSRS Reports always have a specific width.  This includes sub-reports. So the answer to your question is no, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks sir, sad to see this simple feature isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Same Report used in SubReport to the Report where you need the sub-report and Resize . If that helps

Comment: Please add some more context. Maybe a link to a documentation or example.

Comment: you have one sub Report in the Main Report from where you are calling the Sub Report. The Sub-Report is a Different Report which is present on your server , I would like to use that Report which is used as the Sub-Report and make your own adjustments .